# How to find the reason for dataimport failed documents?

Tags: solr

I am trying to reindex data in solr 7.7.1. The response after importing is:

```
 "Total Documents Failed": "595",
```

This might be the number of documents I have added. So I believe there is something wrong with my db import query. However I can not find any error log entries. Might this be an a problem with the unique identifier?

The sql query seems to be valid as directly I can issue it successfully.

```
<entity name="watches" 
        transformer="LogTransformer"
        logTemplate="watches attributes import for classified ID ${classifieds.ID}" logLevel="info"
        query="SELECT
                    a.URL AS url_article,
                    a.article_id,
                    catr_ref.attr_de AS refnumber,
                    cw.ref_id,
                    cw.year,   
                    cw.box,
                    cw.papers,

                    cw.dial_c_id AS dial_id,                                  
                    CONCAT (cw.dial_c_id, '#', catr_dial.attr_de) AS dial,

                    cw.power_reserve,   
                    /* CONCAT (ca_power.value, '#', catr_power.attr_de) AS power, */

                    cw.dial_n_id,                                    
                    CONCAT (cw.dial_n_id, '#', catr_dialn.attr_de) AS dialn,

                    cw.bracelet_type_id,                                    
                    CONCAT (cw.bracelet_type_id, '#', catr_bra_t.attr_de) AS brace_t,

                    cw.case_m_id AS case_id,                                  
                    CONCAT (cw.case_m_id, '#', catr_case.attr_de) AS caseing,

                    cw.water_id, 
                    CONCAT (cw.water_id, '#', catr_water.attr_de) AS water,

                    cw.winding_id,                                  
                    CONCAT (cw.winding_id, '#', catr_wind.attr_de) AS winding,

                    cw.availability AS avail_id,
                    CONCAT (cw.availability, '#', catr_avail.attr_de) AS avail,

                    cw.cond AS cond_id,
                    CONCAT (cw.cond, '#', catr_cond.attr_de) AS cond,

                    /* mark unique watch article to colapse later. e.g. ref#color#bracelet */
                    CONCAT (cw.ref_id, '#', cw.dial_c_id) AS unique_watch
               FROM
                    classifieds_watches AS cw 
               LEFT JOIN cat_attr AS catr_ref   ON catr_ref.attr_id     =  cw.ref_id
               LEFT JOIN cat_attr AS catr_dial  ON catr_dial.attr_id    =  cw.dial_c_id
               LEFT JOIN cat_attr AS catr_dialn ON catr_dialn.attr_id   =  cw.dial_n_id
               LEFT JOIN cat_attr AS catr_bra_t ON catr_bra_t.attr_id   =  cw.bracelet_type_id
               LEFT JOIN cat_attr AS catr_case  ON catr_case.attr_id    =  cw.case_m_id
               LEFT JOIN cat_attr AS catr_water ON catr_water.attr_id   =  cw.water_id
               LEFT JOIN cat_attr AS catr_wind  ON catr_wind.attr_id    =  cw.winding_id
               LEFT JOIN cat_attr AS catr_avail ON catr_avail.attr_id   =  cw.availability
               LEFT JOIN cat_attr AS catr_cond ON catr_cond.attr_id     =  cw.cond                           
               LEFT JOIN articles AS a ON cw.article_id = a.article_id
               WHERE 
                    cw.cl_id  = ${classifieds.id}">
</entity>
```

After playing around a while I figured that the field "year" is responsible for it, as if I set the value to NULL inside the dataset, it will import to solr.

The type:

```
     <field name="year" type="tint" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false" />
    <fieldType name="tint" class="solr.TrieIntField" precisionStep="8" omitNorms="true" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
```

in MySQL it is of type `year(4)`

Looks good as far as I can see. Why is this a problem?

Comment: Are all fields that are set to required present? (i.e. usually `id` at least which doesn't seem to be present, depending on your schema there might be more). Additionally field names are case sensitive in the schema, so it'll depend on what your active schema is.

Comment: Yes. I have 2 fields. id and type. The later one is defined as template. id is set within the major sql query I have not posted. I found that all new added classifieds will not get imported and do guess that there is a value within that dataset that solr does not like. Could that be the case? Is there an easier way to find the cause, like a logentry why the documents failed?

Comment: @MatsLindh I narrowed it down and updated question

Comment: Could it be that the `year` datatype from MySQL is wrapped in a custom class instead of being parsed as a number? You could try CAST(year AS unsigned) AS year